# My docker-compose up is no longer working and cannot start mariadb

Tags: macos, docker

I started using a mac and use docker to develop my sites. Until 12 ago my projects were running properly.

The last activity I tried to on the machine was to install brew mysql, which I already removed. After I restarted my machine, I noticed that I can no longer start any docker container and view a project.

I cd into my project folder and run

```
docker-compose up
```

The following error shows up:

```
Sydney-de-Sousas-Mac:scottishleader.co.za sidney$ docker-compose up
Starting scottishleader_mariadb ... error

ERROR: for scottishleader_mariadb  Cannot start service mariadb: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint scottishleader_mariadb (30a2e258468e8840ca5e67a535835603770afadab58b3e460e624ae3ba587293): Error starting userland proxy: /forwards/expose/port returned unexpected status: 500

ERROR: for mariadb  Cannot start service mariadb: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint scottishleader_mariadb (30a2e258468e8840ca5e67a535835603770afadab58b3e460e624ae3ba587293): Error starting userland proxy: /forwards/expose/port returned unexpected status: 500
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
Sydney-de-Sousas-Mac:scottishleader.co.za sidney$
```

I run docker ps and no container is listed

```
Sydney-de-Sousas-Mac:scottishleader.co.za sidney$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

Why can I suddenly not start the container?

Comment: restart docker daemon ?

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: it says ~bash:service: command not found. Am on mac

Comment: you need to make it then from `docker desktop` icon -> restart

Comment: @LinPy, I just reinstalled docker, cd into my project folder and docker-compose up. Is it normal for it to take too long?

Comment: no it is not ...this isue is similar to yours on mac https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3277

Comment: Are you using windows 10 ?